# ram usage is too high after update of fglrx driver

Tags: ati, fglrx, ram

yesterday when i update my computer it asked new version of fglrx driver available to use? so i choose new version. after i notified my ram usage is too high so my computer is too slow and stuck for a while and while

- os-kubuntu 14.04 64bit
- Asus n53ta Laptop with 4GB ram and 8GB swap
- ATI RADEON 6740G2 2GB

[image: ram and swap]

[image: procesess]

please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this steps solved my problem,

- change fglrx driver to xrog display wrapper
- purge remove fglrx driver
- reinstall fglrx driver

if not solved
change your

- Compositing system to **XRender**

  and
- Qt graphics system to **Native**